# Custom Oauth token storage for flask-dance with mongoengine

Tags: python, mongodb, flask, mongoengine, flask-dance

I'm trying to implement a Custom Token storage that works with MongoDB and stores a session token of flask-dance.
See here for more details:
https://flask-dance.readthedocs.io/en/latest/storages.html

Does someone know how to do this?